# sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed: agent refused operation (ePass2003)

Tags: ssh-keys

Configuring SSH Keys from ePass2003 to access servers.

I have a guest ubuntu 16.04 on VirtualBox, i am able to SSH server 1 from VM but while SSH to server 2 from server 1, getting below error.

```
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opensc-pkcs11.so
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg rsa-sha2-512 blen 279
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: fp SHA256:M0HzYuvGQ8LcKpJIGPgQDrN6Xs8jpyjH4wRQdslGeV
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA SHA256:M0HzYuvGQ8LcKpJIGPgQDrN6Xs8jpyjH4wRQdslGeV
**sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed: agent refused operation**
```

When i run *ssh-add -l* on server 2, i can see the below output.

```
$ ssh-add -l
error fetching identities for protocol 1: agent refused operation
2048 SHA256:M0HzYuvGQ8LcKpJIGPgQDrN6Xs8jpyjH4wRQdslGeV /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opensc-pkcs11.so (RSA)
```

I have made *AllowAgentForwarding yes* in */etc/ssh/sshd_config* file. But still no luck in getting SSH connection to Server2 from Server1.
If anyone can help me getting through this would be great.

Thanks in Advance !!

Answer (score 8):

I'd just like to add that I saw the same issue (in Ubuntu 18.04) and it was caused by bad permissions on my private key files.  I did `chmod 600` on the relevant files and the problem was resolved.  Not sure why ssh-agent didn't complain about this until today.

Comment: Even fixed my windows setup :P

Answer (score 5):

I was able to get the fix for connection issue with SSH Keys. I had to make changes in SSH config files at location ***/etc/ssh/ssh_config*** and ***~/.ssh/config***

```
$ cat ~/.ssh/config
Host *
Compression yes
ForwardAgent yes
ForwardX11Trusted no
GSSAPIAuthentication no
PreferredAuthentications=publickey
```

and

```
$ cat /etc/ssh/ssh_config
Host *
ForwardAgent yes
ForwardX11Trusted yes
HashKnownHosts yes
GSSAPIAuthentication no
GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no
```

After above changes, restart **ssh-agent** and do **ssh-add**.

```
$ eval $(ssh-agent)
$ ssh-add -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opensc-pkcs11.so
```

I hope this should work with you all as well if you come across such issues.

Comment: In my case there is no config in ~/.ssh but changing ssh_config in /etc/ssh and then restarting ssh-agent and then calling ssh-add worked

Answer (score 1):

We only need to execute this time.

```
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
Ssh-add
```

That's OK.

Answer (score -1):

kind of random, but make sure your network isn't blocking it. I was at a hotel and I couldn't ssh into a server. I tried connecting in through my phones hotspot and it worked immediately. Give a different network a try as a quick way to trouble shoot.